# How to receive an image send as octet-stream type in the rest service?

Tags: java, image, file, inputstream, resteasy

I have a rest client that sends a multipart form data. I am sending an image as "application/octet-stream". The image type is JPEG.

How should I correctly receive this in the REST service ?

Currently i am receiving it as `InputStream`.
I converted this input stream to a file,but i am unable to open it.It says `error in jpeg` while trying to open it.

**Input stream to File Conversion logic**

```
File image=File.createTempFile("image", ".JPEG");
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream, image);
```

For clarity i am sharing the rest client stub and the rest service implementations.

Rest client stub

```
public class ImageTest 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
        ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/rest/AS/uploadreceipt");

        MultipartFormDataOutput formData = new MultipartFormDataOutput();

        Map<String, Object> json = new HashMap<>();

        json.put("loyaltyId", "23");

        formData.addFormData("json", json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("/root/Downloads/index.jpeg"));

    formData.addFormData("image", fis, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);

        Entity<MultipartFormDataOutput> entity = Entity.entity(formData, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

        Response response = target.request().post(entity);


    }
```

**Rest service processing**

```
Map<String, Object> json = receiptUploadRequest.getFormDataPart("json", new GenericType<Map<String, Object>>() {});

InputStream image = receiptUploadRequest.getFormDataPart("image", new GenericType<InputStream>() {});
```

Is there anything i need to consider like headers,etc..because its send as a octet-stream from rest client.something is preventing to create a file..**Can anyone please help me convert the image sent from rest client stub to a file**....

Comment: To begin with, don't consume the first byte of the file by reading it prematurely if you want the whole file content to be included in the form data.

Comment: hi john..how can i stop consuming first byte reading prematurely ?

Comment: In this case, you avoid invoking `fis.read()` (or any other method that reads data from the stream)  in the client's `main()`.

Comment: removed fis.read()..still the same error :|

Comment: john..can you please help..

Comment: Sorry, I've got nothing else.  I assume there's something wrong with how you're using the RESTeasy API, but I don't know it well enough to know what, and the documentation is abysmal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was setting the input stream object to a a corresponding pojo field.This was causing corruption in the input stream.
Hence before setting to a pojo field,i converted the input stream to a file.The file created is perfect now.

Answer (score 0):

Do not invoke `fis.read()`, because it is consuming the first byte of your image stream.

Maybe you should include in your question the code that transforms client input stream into a file.

Comment: i have already included it anducs above...File conversion logic heading

Comment: How do you transform `InputStream image` into a file?

Comment: File image=File.createTempFile("image", ".JPEG");
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream, image);